# Dynamically Adding New Options to a Hash

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here's my silly question regarding jQuery that I should probably know.  It's in regards to using jQuery and Handlebar templates.

I set a context hash in my code as follows (similar to the example @ http://www.handlebarsjs.com/):

```
context = {id: 1}
```

All I want to do is dynamically add some elements to that in a loop.  I'm simply pulling some values from a form, setting them as variables, and adding them in using "field_name" and "field_input" for the aforementioned data.

I can't seem to find anything that works, tried append, push, etc. with no luck - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access it as you would normal hash object

```
context["id"] = 1;
```

or simply

```
context.id = 1;
```

Comment: @sshefer Yes, and that is how you do it.